# Comparing and removing rows of CSV file in python?

Tags: python, list, csv

I have a csv file that looks something similar to this.

```
"title","keep","get_rid","keep","rubbish"
"hello_world",1,0,0,0
"goodbye_world",0,0,1,0
"to_string",1,0,1,0
"not_so_smart",1,0,0,0
```

The goal is to remove the columns of which do not contain an instance of 1. So in this example, "get-rid" and "rubbish" will be removed - leaving us with something like...

```
"title","keep", "keep"
"hello_world",1,0
"goodbye_world",0,1
"to_string",1,1
"not_so_smart",1,0
```

However, I have somehow struggled to perform what seemed to be initially a simple problem.

My failed solution currently looks like this...

```
with open("filename.csv", "rb") as file:
reader = csv.reader(file)
header = next(reader)
for i, columns in enumerate(reader):
    for j, rows in enumerate(columns):
        if "1" not in rows[1:]:
```

Which isn't working as expected. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

the `1` should be `str` type, but not the `int` type.

```
if '1' not in columns
```